# Gradient support for IE 8 and below

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gradient

I found a great CSS [gradient code generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/) for a page my friend is making, but there are some comments below it that worry me:

```
/* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#cccccc, endColorstr=#ffffff);
        /* For Internet Explorer 8 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#cccccc, endColorstr=#ffffff)";    
        background-color: #CCC;
```

And in reply:

> I strongly recommend against these! They do not act the same, are limited, hurt performance, and can cause layout issues. Simply put, since IE does not support gradients (and many other CSS features natively, without filter), either use images for the same effect (background image) or convince your client that IE users get less of an experience (who seriously cares about gradients vs single colours besides insane 'designers'?) because their browser just doesn't match up to what we as developers want. It's called graceful degradation and IE should not be any exception to that.

So what I don't know is: Should I suggest they do/do not use any of this code? Is getting IE to use this code useless/hopeless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter stuff is generally regarded as bad practice, and isn't valid CSS (so your stylesheet will fail validation tests)

it's possible to set a background image for the element in question, then IE will fallback to that image if it's a version that doesn't support gradients, the beauty of it is that browsers supporting gradients don't load the background image (well, usually) so performance isn't impacted negatively.

Personally, if I were you I'd go for the background image solution, it's a lot cleaner than the whole "filter" thing, and doesn't punish people not using Internet Explorer (yay!)

If you'd like more detail, see here:
http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: Gradient images aren't an alternative in most use cases, as they don't stretch or shrink to fit the element the are used on. How does a filter-rule punish non IE users? If you like to have cleaner/valid CSS files, you could move those rules to a separate `ie.css`. Where did you read that "The filter stuff is generally regarded as bad practice". This is your personal opinion.

Comment: @feela - Bad practice may be the wrong term but filters aren't standard and vendor prefixes are. You only need to remember the prefix for each browser but, like most things IE related, you have to stand on  your head and wave your arms to get things to work.

Comment: @feeela why the concern over IE, but not any other browser that doesn't support gradients?  I know it's hard to imagine people that use an "alternative" browser but don't keep it up to date, but I caught a client with an antique version of Safari just last year.  Either the information the gradient conveys is important or it's not (if it is important, what are you doing for the blind?).  If it's not, then you can treat it like any other browser that doesn't support gradients.  It's worth noting that the IE filters only work with 2 color stops.

Comment: @cimmanon "why the concern over IE" Because all my customers set it as a requirement and do pay for it. And not quite bad. But no customer does pay for a fix for Firefox 2. That's the whole reason why – free market economy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to create CSS gradients. THe code produced there works even in IE 6+:

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

So yes, you could use gradients in MS IE.

Comment: Yes I know that `filter` isn't part of the CSS specification – but on the other hand was IE 8 the first Microsoft browser for Windows to support CSS 2.1. So when it comes to styling for MS IE I don't care about what any specification says. Otherwise I couldn't create CSS layouts for those browsers. (This comment was a reply, but the comment before was deleted…)

Comment: I'm feeling feeela's comments. It's tough when there's a supposed specification, yet browsers, past and current, don't support the specification throughout. What is the point of specifications if browsers are created not following them? Seems like a nicety to follow but validation is just an opinion at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Four years after the question was asked, the issue has not gone away.  I do a lot of sites for large corporates and you still find IE8 on the corporate desktop, sometimes even as the company standard.

My recommendation would be to take those lines exactly as they are offered.  IE8 will use them, and any modern browser will ignore them.  It keeps the designer happy that you are implementing his design to the best of the browser's ability, but you don't have to mess about with striped background images.

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Internet Explorer 5 - 7 */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#cccccc, endColorstr=#ffffff);
        /* For Internet Explorer 8 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#cccccc, endColorstr=#ffffff)";    
        background-color: #CCC;
```